# Not able to install php-fpm in Openshift PHP s2i base image

Tags: php, dependencies, package, dockerfile, openshift

In OpenShift, I'm using rhscl_php-71-rhel7 s2i base image.

I need to install rh-php71-php-fpm.
I usually do this with Dockerfile.

```
FROM rhscl_php-71-rhel7:latest
USER root
RUN yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms \
     && yum install -y -q -v \
     rh-php71-php-fpm-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64 \
     && yum clean all \
     && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
USER 1001
```

But installing fails over a dependency, a newer package is already present.

Part of the log:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rh-php71-php-fpm.x86_64 0:7.1.8-1.el7 will be installed
...
rh-php71-php-fpm-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64 requires: systemd-sysv
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-sysv for package: rh-php71-php-fpm-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
...
TSINFO: Marking systemd-sysv-219-62.el7_6.2.x86_64 as install for rh-php71-php-fpm-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package systemd-sysv.x86_64 0:219-62.el7_6.2 will be installed
Checking deps for systemd-sysv.x86_64 0:219-62.el7_6.2 - u
...
systemd-sysv-219-62.el7_6.2.x86_64 requires: systemd = 219-62.el7_6.2
--> Processing Dependency: systemd = 219-62.el7_6.2 for package: systemd-sysv-219-62.el7_6.2.x86_64
Searching pkgSack for dep: systemd
Potential resolving package systemd-219-62.el7_6.2.x86_64 has newer instance installed.
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Dependency Process ending
Error: Package: systemd-sysv-219-62.el7_6.2.x86_64 (rhel-7-server-rpms)
           Requires: systemd = 219-62.el7_6.2
           Installed: systemd-219-62.el7_6.3.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.6)
systemd = 219-62.el7_6.3
```

Are there any options to have the package installed, despite the presence of a newer dependency?

Comment: This image name `rhscl_php-71-rhel7:latest` might be typo, I think it woule be `rhscl/php-71-rhel7:latest`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM rhscl/php-71-rhel7:latest
USER root
RUN yum-config-manager --enable rhel-7-server-rpms --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms \
     && yum install -y -q -v \
     rh-php71-php-fpm-7.1.8-1.el7.x86_64 \
     && yum clean all \
     && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
USER 1001
```

`systemd-sysv` is package of `rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms`repo, if you add this repository to your host or `Dockerfile`, then the `systemd-sysv` will be updated and resolve the dependencies for your image build.

Comment: That did it, tnx!